# Android Cordova device.uuid does it require permission?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store, cordova-plugins

Hi I am trying to find out if using

cordova-plugin-device device.uuid requires a special permission in the android manifest.

I checked the website and couldn't see anything for Android 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

Everything works fine I am just wondering in my app store does this require a special permission for me to use the Phone UUID.

Comment: I am using cordova 4.0.0; device.uuid works fine with cordova-plugin-device set in the project. When I look in the content of the plugin.xml file of the plugin, inside the android tag, I notice that there is no instruction to alter the manifest.xml of the project. This said, (an information that might interest you in the near future) I've noticed that also while device.uuid value is consistent on an android device, it is not the case on an iOS one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Cordova-plugin-device does not require any permission.

cordova automatically adds required permissions in all the platforms when you add a plugin, so you don't need to manually edit android manifest file.

if you want to know which plugin requires which permissions have a look at

```
<project directory>/plugins/<plugin directory>/plugin.xml
```

if plugin uses any permission you will be able to see it inside `<platform name="android">` with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SomePermission" />`